# Creating a million objects with 12 doubles each

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, matrix

I am an intermediate level programmer. I am trying to create a simulation program which needs a million objects of a class to be created. Each of those objects will contain seven 12x12 matrices. (I know this is a lot of memory). I tried to use 2D vectors. But when I run it is always killed by the OS(Ubuntu). I tried to use "new" and 2D double arrays (because I read that new will put the memory on heap). But the process is always killed.

I am allocating the arrays and the vector of objects as follows

12x12 matrices

```
    ObjectMatrix = new double*[matSize];
    for(int i = 0; i < matSize; ++i) {
            ObjectMatrix[i] = new double[matSize];
    }
```

a vector of million objects each containing 7 of such 12x12 matrices

```
    for(int i=0;i<=1E6;i++){
       ObjectVector *newObj = new Object();
       ObjectVector.push_back(newObj);
    }
```

Is there a way to solve this problem and create a vector of 1 or more million objects ?

Comment: If the process is killed by the OS it's probably a memory issue. You are asking for too much memory too quickly. I assume your system has enough memory to be allocated. (haven't done the math)

Comment: `8 bytes * 144 doubles * 7 matrices * 1000000 objects = approx 7 gigs...`

Comment: Use floats and check the ulimit command.

Comment: Also, check that you are targeting a 64-bit application.  32-bit applications only support 4G of address space.

Comment: Have you considered solutions based on lazy evaluation? Perhaps you don't really need the actual values of all elements of the vector but only some of them.

Comment: @ChristianHackl Thanks for the suggestion. This Lazy evolution looks interesting. I will try to formulate in this approach and will post my result.

Answer (score 0):

You should create your matrix in one piece of memory.

```
double* matrix = new double[matSize*matSize];
```

This way you're saving matSize*sizeof(double*) memory.

And you should create you objects as an array.

```
Object* objects = new Object[number];
```

Here you can save again alot of unnecessary pointers.

Comment: I would also add a usleep() in the allocation loop to avoid cpu hug. Together with the big amount of requested memory, can be the reason why the kernel kills the process (reclaming too much system resources)

Comment: Thank you @dari ... But that did not work. I think the process could assign more elements this time with your suggestions, but finally it is killed.

Comment: @AdityaG : how much RAM do you have on the system? cabbellicar123 calculated you need around 8 GB or RAM to allocate all the memory

Comment: @sergico ... I have 16GB ... !